# Check if database has support for transactions using FireDac

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7, dbexpress, firedac

How can I check if the DBMS has support for Transactions, using FireDac components?
Usually, I use something like the follow code, to perform a transaction in my DAO class, using dbExpress.

```
...
connection: TSQLConnection;
dbxTransaction: TDBXTransaction;
... 

if (connection.TransactionsSupported) AND ((not connection.InTransaction) OR (connection.MultipleTransactionsSupported)) then
begin
    dbxTransaction := connection.BeginTransaction(TDBXIsolations.ReadCommitted);
end;
```

So, what are the correspondents properties in FireDac that I use in dbExpress:
`TransactionsSupported`
`InTransaction`
`MultipleTransactionsSupported`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- TransactionsSupported - TFDConnection.ConnectionMetaDataIntf.TxSupported
- InTransaction - TFDConnection.InTransaction
- MultipleTransactionsSupported - TFDConnection.ConnectionMetaDataIntf.TxMultiple